# log4j appender by class

Tags: java, apache, logging, log4j, appender

I've written a log4j appender that will take a certain message type and dump it to a MongoDB cluster.  Let's call it "Audit"

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
logger.debug (new AuditEntry (...));
```

from ANY class and have log4j automatically route any log messages of type "AuditEntry" to my Audit appender.  Is this possible?  The only way I've been able to do this so far is to add it the appender to the rootLogger chain:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, Console, Audit
```

But then of course the AuditEntry also is toString()'d out to the Console -- I'd like to avoid this if possible.

I have thought of one solution but I'm not sure if it's the best solution.  Make the Audit filter the first in the chain:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, Audit, Console
```

and then inside my log4j appender call "clearFilterChain()"  I haven't tried this yet... nor have I found any documentation on this function.

Any other solutions?

Comment: Any reason you wish to use log4j here? Why not just write a class called Audit with a static createAudit method, or similar. You seem to want to

Comment: Damn iPhone keyboard. You seem to want to block the default log4j behaviour, so why use it?

Comment: I wanted to use log4j to have more control over where the messages are routed -- mongo, file, oracle db, etc.  All controlled by a simple configuration file.  But... it looks like I might have to abandon log4j

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable log4j in 3rd party jar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732981/how-to-disable-log4j-in-3rd-party-jar)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that.  We want to log from any class.